# Freemarker - if else condition not working

Tags: java, freemarker

In my `ftl` file, I'm writing:

```
<#list myDataList as myData>
<p>
    <#if myData.action == 0>Added by
    <#else>Removed from
    </#if>
</p>
</#list>
```

In java code, action is of type Integer.

I've also tried `myData.action == "0"`.

I can see `action == 0` while debugging.

**Error I'm getting:**

```
freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> myData.action  [in template "email_template.ftl" at line 79, column 50]
```

Comment: Try with default value as `myData.action!"0" == "0"` or  `(myData.action)!"0" == "0"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @user7294900 Default values need not be a strings. So it should be this to avoid any number formatting issues (like the `action` is present, and then auto converted to `0.0`): `myData.action!0 == 0`

Answer (score 0):

`null` is different from `0` (zero). Try a "[Missing value test](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_missing_test)" instead:

```
myData.action?? == false
```